# Import .FLA into Flash Builder 4

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flash-builder

Is there a way to import FLA files into Flash Builder 4 such as conversion to SWC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. If you want to compile a FLA into a SWC you need Flash Professional.

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to convert in .swc using Flash Professional CS4 or CS5. Flash builder 4 is for creating flex applications using .swc files if required.